# ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier returns always null in Blazor WebAssembly ASP.NET Core Hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-authorization, blazor-webassembly

I have setup a `Blazor WebAssembly ASP.NET Core hosted`application and integrated the authentication system as well as the custom `AuthenticationProvider` to the client. In the server side project I am calling in the controller this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetObjects()
{
   var id = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); // <-- returns always null
}
```

and the `id` variable is always returning null.

The user is from the aspnetcoreuser table (aspnetcore identity)
In the table data I can see, as I am using SQLite, that the id is not null and ther users got added succesfully to the `aspnetuser` table.

Some SDK-Versions:

> .NET Core SDKs installed:
> 3.1.301 .NET Core runtimes installed:    Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.19 Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.19Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.5 Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.19 Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.5
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.5

Also I have seen some solutions that the `"windowsAuthentication": true, "anonymousAuthentication": false,` from the `launchSettings.json` can cause that but with changes it does not solved it for me.

Anyone here who can help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `UserIdClaimType` on the server app by adding this code to `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => 
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#usermanager-and-signinmanager)

Comment: Thanks for the response! It's right there was the server dependency missing but now I am getting an Exception: `System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

Comment: I have noticed that the User generally is null inside the controller. Am I missing any dependency registration? Thought the controller has access to the user by default without integrating any httpcontext.

Comment: what is the server app setup? In client/server model we should use the access token to call a protected resource API in the server app. and server app should be setup to read the token and being authorized - Can you confirm this is what you have in place?

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Helped cleared up my issue of GetUserAsync(User) returning Null. Had to set it to the correct ClaimTypes.